# Trying to get access to a property using filter in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have isolated a value of userId and then I am trying to make a network request and trying to gain access to the email property by matching up the userId from the returned JSON and I am having a problem with that.

I made the network request, I have the property of userId and now from the network request I am iterating over the JSON and based on the userId I just trying to find the email.

```
Let emailRecipient = Observable<String>
var givenUserId = "8975949584358490"
networkRequest
.asObservable() 
.map{projectUsers in if projectUsers.filter{$0.userId == givenUserId}.first{
 //Here I want to set the emailRecipient property to .email Property of the projectUser 
}}
```

Comment: Normally you wouldn't use the closure in a .map function as a place for side effects.  You can if-let your whole expression and set your property when the thing you're looking for is actually found.

Answer (score 0):

**After chatting, I think I have a better understanding of the code you posted above.**

Don't filter over your observable, but rather over the array you receive when you subscribe to it.

```
// These properties are persisted in the class or somewhere outside of the scope of the subscription
var searchResult = Variable("")

let searchId = "8975949584358490"

...
// Elsewhere

// Assuming networkRequest returns an observable of an array of users
let subscription = networkRequest
    .asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { fetchedUsers in 
    if let foundUser = fetchedUsers.first(where: {$0.userId == searchId}) {
        searchResult.value = foundUser.email
    }
})
```

Comment: Also note that when providing a closure for .first, your'e looking for some boolean condition to be met to find that first instance you're looking for in the sequence.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No prob!  If this solution works for you, be sure to accept the answer.

Comment: I just have one question, it isn't really working for me. I wanted to post some code and show you,

Comment: networkRequest
            .asObservable()
            .map({projectUsers in if projectUsers.filter{ projectUsers.userId == userIdsFromEmailDetails}.first
                { correctUser in
                return correctUser
                }}) {
                self.emailRecipients.value = correctUser.email
        }

Comment: I don't know the entirety of your code, but I think .first alone should serve here.  Let me adjust the example.

Comment: So the userId also has an email property, once the userId matches up then that particular user's email is what I need. There is no other condition that I am passing that user to, I just that particular user and the email property on that user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197519/discussion-between-kid-x-and-sara).